# Strange HttpException that's driving me nuts

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5, properties, episerver

Im trying to list all categories in a VPP-folder using a module from Meridium called [*FolderBrowserProperty*.](https://www.coderesort.com/p/epicode/wiki/FolderBrowserProperty) It works perfectly locally and on our company's remote test site, but on the live site we are getting the following error:

---

Server Error in '/' Application.

```
Unhandled Execution Error

Stack trace:

[HttpException: 0x80004005]<br>
System.Web.CachedPathData.GetConfigPathData(String configPath) +459 
System.Web.CachedPathData.GetVirtualPathData(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean permitPathsOutsideApp) +132 <br>
System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetConfig(VirtualPath path) +110  
System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule.CheckUrlAccessForPrincipal(String virtualPath, IPrincipal user, String verb) +477 <br>
EPiServer.Security.PrincipalInfo.HasPathAccess(String path) +88 
EPiServer.Web.Hosting.VersioningDirectory.getDirectories() +229 
EPiServer.Web.Hosting.VersioningDirectory.GetDirectories() +35 
EPiServer.Web.WebControls.FileSystemItem.getChildren() +92 
EPiServer.Web.WebControls.FileSystemItem.get_HasChildren() +5 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.DataBindRecursive(TreeNode node, 
IHierarchicalEnumerable enumerable, Boolean ignorePopulateOnDemand) +3652 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.DataBindRecursive(TreeNode node, 
IHierarchicalEnumerable enumerable, Boolean ignorePopulateOnDemand) +3752 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.DataBindRecursive(TreeNode node, 
IHierarchicalEnumerable enumerable, Boolean ignorePopulateOnDemand) +3752 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.DataBindNode(TreeNode node) +347 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.PerformDataBinding() +305 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.HierarchicalDataBoundControl.PerformSelect() +82 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.DataBind() +70 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.DataBind() +4 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +82 
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +43 
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +86 
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +170 
System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +170 
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2041
```

---

We first assumed there was an access problem (WindowsMembershipProvider), but both the IIS and the active using accessing the files have access - still same problem. 
I've looked around abit on the methods executing before and at the error, but due to the exception message, i cant deduce anything helpful.

Any help will be most appreciative.

Best regards,
Mattias

---

I forgot to update this thread. Of course the devil here was EPiServer :) I found your solution 2 weeks ago and it worked!

Comment: At what "level" did you determine that the user has access? Does the user account in which the process is executing have the required access in the file system?

Comment: Yes it does. We tried to set access for 'everyone' just to see if it really was an access problem, but it still generated the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of EPiServer are you using?

There was an old known bug with the exact same stacktrace in EPiServer R1 known as:

Issue 9716: File management crashs when folder name ends with "."

Could it be that the folder added ended with a "."? The bug should be fixed in R1SP2. You can verify if it is that bug you're affected by if you can get the same exception by browsing the folders with EPiServers file manager.